# MySQL on docker containers

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm exploring on how to use MySQL inside docker containers.I have following questions on the same.

1. Best practices to store data and how we can ship MySQL containers with data if required ?
2. Need to access MySQL data from outside.

Can someone suggest ideas or share some reference url's for the same ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you should check the doc on docker'site

https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

For 2, you have many great tutorials on that subject

http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/11/creating-a-mysql-docker-container/

http://www.luiselizondo.net/a-tutorial-on-how-to-use-mysql-with-docker/

The Mysql container will publish some ports (3306 or any other) on your host, and you will access them from outside, like if you had started Mysql on your host.